# Which tool can tell me the distribution of Linux that is running when uname is generic?

Tags: linux

I normally use `uname` to determine which OS is running, but I have accounts on several machines where I don't know the particular distribution that is running.

When `uname` returns **Linux**, I tried `uname -a` and I see only the following:

```
 Linux host123 3.0.58-0.6.6-pae blah blah blah i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

My guess is this is a SUSE distribution, but is there a better way to know which distribution is installed similar to how `uname` normally shows AIX, Darwin, etc...?

Comment: @manatwork Once I asked this, I did find the linked question, but I really don't care about the version number details and wanted a simple, clear next step tool to break down what Linux means when uname reports it. The other long scripting questions didn't hit any of my search terms so I figured I'd document what I found for others to find.

Answer (score 5):

Once you get Linux from `uname` you can run (or check for the existence of) `lsb_release` and run it with the `-si` switch if you just want the Distributor ID:

```
 user@host123:~> lsb_release -si
 SUSE LINUX
```

Similarly, both `uname -a` and `lsb_release -a` give more detailed build information. Alternatively, `cat /etc/issue` gives fairly reliable information on the distribution of Linux.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer, however, this is the same answer as given in the accepted one of the duplicate question, which is why your question was closed.

Comment: No worries - I'm quite familiar with moderation on the SE network even if I don't come by this section of it often. Thanks for making sure I knew what was up :-)

Comment: Ah, yes, just checked your profile :).

Comment: Also, once I finally found out about `lsb_release`, I figured you'd all dupe this with http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31170/why-doesnt-uname-a-return-a-useful-identifier or http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35183/how-do-i-identify-which-linux-distro-is-running but in the end - it's all good since the index is so great at searching closed questions.